# How to clear react-native cache?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

In react-native development, there are multiple caches used when the app is built:

1. React-native packager cache
2. Emulator cache
3. Java side cache (.gradle) folder (only in android)
4. npm cache (if relevant?)

Am I missing something also? Because I'm trying to clear cache in react-native, to be able to repeat a bug that only occurs on first usage. But clearing those caches above did not help. This is on android. When the app is building, most of the rows DO NOT say UP-TO-DATE, as expected, because I cleared the cache.

But, there are still many rows where this text is printed. Like:

> app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

The question is, how can I clear the whole cache related to react-native development?

Answer (score 187):

For React Native Init approach (without expo) use:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: This helped me to fix [`Error: unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539122/8740349)

Comment: can this be done without starting the metro bundler?

Comment: For better approach, before this command close metro bundler and run this.

Comment: How do i only reset catch without starting npm ?

Comment: What does the `--` do?

Comment: @kojow7 '--' separate options from arguments. Everything after -- npm won't read as option and will pass along to start script  (most unix/linux commands follow this option/argument separation convention)

Comment: I use this in package.json, in section "scripts": {
 "clear": "pid=$(lsof -i :8081 -a -c node -t) && kill $pid; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; npm start -- --reset-cache",

Comment: Awesome, helped me fix issue:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1798

Comment: it opens metro and stops there, then nothing happens

Comment: Does this clean `node_modules`, `ios/build`, `ios/Pods`, and `android/build`?

Answer (score 130):

Simplest one(react native,npm and expo )

For React Native

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

for npm

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

for Expo

```
expo start -c
```

Comment: I get "error: unknown option `--reset-cache'" what should I do...?

Comment: @Leonard try with `yarn cache clean`

Answer (score 48):

Clearing the Cache of your React Native Project:

npm < 6.0 and RN < 0.50:

```
 watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* &&
 rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && 
 npm start -- --reset-cache
```

npm >= 6.0 and RN >= 0.50:

```
 watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
 rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force &&
 npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: This seems the only way possible once got stuck with errors generated from cache that has old code. Really a pain if debugging and used some "console.log" in the RN code. Anyone has some more shorter solution, I mean to avoid that the RN framework use cached code?

Comment: Some considerations. 1) not always $TMPDIR variable is defined. 2)  watchman command isn't always used. You can remove that part of the command or use ';' instead of '&&' after it 3) the dir names might differ. Mine is /tmp/metro-cache/ , not metro-bundler-cache-something...(RN 0.62)

Comment: The best solution I would say

Comment: Both `npm start` and `npx react-native start` were hanging with no feedback in console whatsoever and this did the trick on RN 0.73.0.

Answer (score 40):

Currently, it is built using `npx`, so it needs to be updated.

**Terminal** : `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

**iOS** : `Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder`

**Android** : `Android Studio -> Build -> Clean Project`

Comment: This helped on an Expo (based on React Native) project that was having problems.

Answer (score 29):

try this

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 22):

For those who are using expo-cli

> expo start -c

Answer (score 13):

This is what works for me:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -f podfile.lock && rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn start --reset-cache
```

Comment: No need to remove your yarn.lock file you'll cause all your dependencies to be updated in the process.

Comment: Same with the podfile.lock, shouldn't be removed

Answer (score 13):

Below commands worked for me for Android and Yarn,

```
cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd .. &&
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&  
yarn cache clean && yarn install && 
yarn start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a great discussion on GitHub which helped me a lot.
[Clearing the Cache of your React Native Project](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) by [Jarret Moses](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses)

There are solutions for 4 different instances.

1. RN <0.50 -
   `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`
2. RN >=0.50 - 
   `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`
3. NPM >=5 - 
   `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`
4. Windows - 
   `del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache`

The solution is similar to [Vikram Biwal's Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache/51375437#51375437)

And there is a discussion below in the given link, so even if the above 4 cases don't work for you, you can scroll through and find a possible solution.

Answer (score 7):

Clearing the Cache of your React Native Project:
if you are sure the module exists, try this steps:

1. Clear watchman watches:
   npm watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules:
   rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache:
   yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Comment: If I try `rm -rf /tmp/metro-*` I get `zsh: no matches found: /tmp/metro-*` I am using RN 0.64.1. Any idea?

Comment: Escaping the star seems to work `rm -rf /tmp/metro-\*`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `WebStorm`, press configuration selection drop down button left of the run button and select edit configurations:

[image: edit configurations]

Double click on `Start React Native Bundler` at bottom in `Before launch` section:

[image: before launch]

Enter `--reset-cache` to `Arguments` section:

[image: arguments]

Answer (score 3):

You can clean cache in React Native >= 0.50 and npm > 5 :

```
watchman watch-del-all && 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rm -rf node_modules/ 
&& npm cache clean --force &&
npm install && 
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Apart from cleaning npm cache you might need to [reset simulator or clean build](https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/how-to-clear-react-native-cache-c435c258834e) etc.

Answer (score 2):

React native

```
 npm start -r-cache
```

or

```
yarn cache clean
```

Expo

```
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 2):

npm start -- --reset-cache

Clean build cache

cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache

https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/how-to-clear-react-native-cache-c435c258834e

Comment: Please [edit] to make the relevant technical difference, or appreciated contibution in explanation, more obvious which this provides beyond the existing answers; because the core steps seem very similar to me. Note that linked content is not considered part of the answer post here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried gradle cleanBuildCache?

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html#clear_the_build_cache

Answer (score 1):

Well.. i want to share my experience about this issue:

I was facing this problem, and when I opened the task manager I notice many tasks being executed, and they were linked to my project folder.

So I restarted my PC, and when it turned on, I could install all I needed, so the problem got solved itself, it worked to me, hope this help somebody...

Answer (score 1):

Run in your terminal: `expo prebuild --clean`

Answer (score 1):

- android
  cd android && ./gradlew clean
- ios
  open xcode then choose product => clear all issue and clean build folder

then yarn start --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

For React Native > v0.7 (without expo) use:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf yarn.lock package-lock.json node_modules
rm -rf android/app/build
rm ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
$TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* $ rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*
npm cache clean --force
yarn cache clean
npm install && cd ios && pod update && cd ..
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I tried to clear all the caches possible (tried almost all the solutions above) and the only thing that worked for me was to kill the expo app and to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I went into this issue today, too. The cause was kinda silly -- `vscode` auto imported something from `express-validator` and caused the bug. 

Just mentioning this in case anyone has done all the steps to clear cache/ delete modules or what not.

Answer (score 0):

For android and Npm

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&  
npm cache clean && yarn install && 
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the below code for a clean ios build:

```
cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd .. && npm run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some cache cleaning scripts to add to your package.json. It includes a 'secret-cache' workaround to clear a cache that is missed by `react-native clean`.

They will clean all the build & react-native caches, but not the package or pod caches, which is usually what you want.

```js
    "clean:gradle": "cd android && ./gradlew --stop; rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*",
    "clean:android": "yarn clean:secret-cache && react-native clean --include android,metro,watchman",
    "clean:ios": "yarn clean:secret-cache && react-native clean --include metro,watchman && cd ios && xattr -w com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem true build && xcodebuild clean; cd ..",
    "clean:secret-cache": "npx react-native start --reset-cache --projectRoot null 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true",
```

The 'secret-cache' script will allow your .env updates to work even if you experience the react native dotenv cache bug:
https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv#cacheing

Add them to package.json then `yarn clean:ios && yarn ios` or `yarn clean:android && yarn android`

In some cases this may still not be enough (e.g. react-native-auth0 still caches auth0Domain). So here's the nuclear option (requires package.json updates above):

```bash
# Nuclear option (100% definitely clean everything) - go get a coffee or something
yarn clean:secret-cache && npx react-native clean-project-auto && yarn clean:gradle && yarn && cd android && ./gradlew assemble
```

Answer (score 0):

To yarn use

```
watchman watch-del-all
yarn --reset-cache
```

Answer (score -2):

#### TO Clear cache in IOS/Xcode

Delete folders in
  `/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
and try again.

```
rm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```