# How to fix util could not be found in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native, I created a sample application for navigation between screen but I am facing some issue. I have attached the screen shot.[image]

code I have used in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import  FirstScreen  from './screens/FirstScreen'
import  SecondScreen  from './screens/SecondScreen'

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
First: {screen: FirstScreen},
Second: {screen: SecondScreen}
});

export default Navigation; // Export your root navigator as the root component
```

second screen code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
const util = require('util');

export default class SecondScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Second screen',
};

render() {
    console.log("this.props.navigation.state = " + util.inspect(this.props.navigation.state, false, null));
    var {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is screen 2</Text>
            <Text>Params from screen1 : {params.name}, email = {params.email}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
  }
```

These code I got form github.

Comment: Post  the code of SecondScreen

Comment: oleg can you check now.

Comment: `util` is a built in module in nodejs,.  I don't use React Native so does it have one too?  In your code it's only using `util.inspect`.  so just change it to console log.

Comment: Keith I dont have much knowledge in react native , But i found util build inside node_module.

Comment: try: npm install util --save

Answer (score -1):

Refer below link. You have to clear cache and run again.

[How to clear react-native cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache)

There would be a chance for a path issue or some error in second screen code. Make a simple hello world on the second screen.