# However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native but not ReactJs iam going to mad about this error from 2 days

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `@react-navigation/native` from file `C:\XXXXX\Example\src\Router.jsx`, the package `C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\index.tsx`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-safe-area-context` from file `C:\XXXXX\Example\App.js`, the package `C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.16.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am downgrade the react-navigation version  to react-navigation 4 and react-navigation-stack
the error become

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-safe-area-context` from file `C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\Stack\StackView.js`, the package `C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\XXXXX\Example\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

I am also deleted node_modules ,clear cache and install again but no use same errors appear

Comment: The answers presented above didn't work for me. I had to [clear the cache of my React Native Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375437/8577483)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

After a long research MetroJS bundler default not compile typescript .ts and .tsx extension files.
We need tell MetroJS bundler to compile .ts and .tsx files
i solved this error by edit **metro.config.js** file in root project folder by following.

**Edited on September 2022**

- Added cjx and json extensions to below snippet
- All extensions listed below not required it's depend on what    language you choose javascript or typescript, and your dependencies

```js
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs', 'json'] //add here
  },
};
```

Comment: where can I find `metro.config.js` file in my react-native project ?

Comment: metro.config.js file located at root folder

Comment: node_modules/metro/src/integration_tests/metro.config.js

Comment: Need to create new file => metro.config.js and then add this code into that file which worked for me.

Comment: In my case I had to create the `metro.config.js` file and populate it using the info from Robin Dowling's post below

Comment: I had this same issue with react-chartjs-2. Solved with metro.config.js PLUS adding cjs to sourceExts. Thanks so much, Jogi!

Comment: Agreed. Make sure to add 'cjs' in there if you are using the latest version of firebase.

Comment: React Native 0.70 will have issues with this config as `app.json` will not be resolved. @JogiPrasadPakki if you don't ming please add `json` extension to the array in your snippet.

Answer (score 54):

The above answers did not work for me. Turns out there was nothing wrong with my files.

I simply had to terminate the react-native metro that was running on the terminal and restarted it, it worked fine.

Comment: If still doesn't work. uninstall the app in emulator and run again it will work.

Answer (score 22):

Adding to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126739/1129493) by Jogi, this issue was acknowledged by the Apollo developers at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#apollo-client-354-2021-11-19

I was unable to resolve the issue with Jogi's answer alone, but after adding `'cjs'` to the array, as recommended in the linked changelog, my app was able to start up as expected.

```js
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 12):

For me, I'm using two terminals to run my app. 1st terminal: `react-native start`, 2nd: `react-native run android`, which builds the app and starts it on my physical device. I got the same error above when I installed a new package and rebuild my app not knowing that I had to restart the react-native server.

So what I just did is went back to 1st terminal, killed it, and re-run `react-native start` then rebuilt my app in the second terminal and everything is working as expected!!!

Answer (score 6):

I had to clear watchman to resolve a similar issue

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Comment: This worked for me! I also uninstalled the app from the simulator

Answer (score 3):

here is how my metro.config.js it looks like after configuring. i am using react-navigato 5*

```
    module.exports = {
        transformer: {
          getTransformOptions: async () => ({
             transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
             },
           }),
         },
          /** include this below (remove this comment too)*/
       resolver: {                              
         sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx'],
       },
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with **react-native-gesture-handler** package.Changing metro.config.js file has worked for me.

```js
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },

  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx'], 
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As many of them already mentioned to customize your **metro.config.js** file. If it is not there create it in the root directory of your project and then add the code as everyone said. Now even after adding the code in **metro.config.js** file error is there, then you have to stop your expo server and restart with command

```
expo start -c
```

This works for me. Hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me.

```
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx','js','ts','tsx'] //add here 
   },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For Expo, this version worked
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6253#issuecomment-1123923581

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions above but none worked. so i did `yarn install` instead of `npm` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Restart worked for me . just close the terminal and run your project again with `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you get this error because you install an npm package that has a main script that's not correctly integrated with your project. This could be because you have named your files differently, you have nested your file a layer deeper and causes a script to break, etc.
Check the package.json file of the package the error message tells you "main" is incorrect and see if it is correctly pointing to the app entry in the package.json of the root directory.
Doing this fixed the error for me.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

for me none of the above worked but this did:
go to :
`node_modules\deprecated-react-native-prop-types\DeprecatedColorPropType.js`

find this line :
`const normalizeColor = require('@react-native/normalize-color');`
and change it to this:
`const normalizeColor = require('@react-native/normalize-color/base');`

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was to kill my metro cmd

Deleted my app from the emulator then,

run `npx react-native run-android` or

if you're using expo run

```
npm start
```

*Error is gone*

Answer (score 0):

kill the already running terminal and start the project by running this command:
**npx react-native start** it will start your app as expected

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.I am using yarn as my package manager. Resolved the issue by following the below steps.

- Stop the metro bundler(In my case i closed terminal which terminated metro bundler).
- Restart it using `yarn start --reset-cache`.
- Run `yarn android`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when trying to load @angular/core. You carefully need to check your error log (as usual ;)). Apparently there are way more file extensions you should add to your metro.config.js, according to the module you are using.

@angular/core e.g. uses d.ts (because it's index.d.ts in the module's folder) so I needed to add it to the array:

```
  sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs', 'json', 'd.ts']
```

After that, of course, a fresh restart is recommended

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after installing a new npm package

---

Solution:

1. closed Android emulator and stopped and closed Metro terminal
2. Restarted the project as always; in my case `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was using `mergeConfig` to merge config settings.

if you have two configs like this:

```js
const config1 = {
    transformer: {
    //...
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: ["js", "json", "ts"],
    },
   }

const config2 = {
    transformer: {
    //...
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: ["tsx", "cjs", "svg"],
    },
   }

mergeConfig(config1, config2)
```

keep in mind that after the merge the `sourceExts` in the latest one will override the inital one.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the error was due to the cache. I followed following steps:

Navigate to android folder

```
cd android
```

after that clean the build folder

```
 ./gradlew clean
```

and to generate the apk file

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

use this to generate aab

```
./gradlew bundleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

I hope these commands will help others as well.