# While trying to resolve module `fs` from file

Tags: react-native, npm, fs, metro-bundler

At first, I got the error :-
module `assert` not found in file `../node_modules/yargs/index.js`
installed `assert`, got same error for `path`, `fs` and installed them as well.

but then I got this error, have spent more than half a day, did not find any valid solution.

BTW I have tried:-

- [However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124435/however-this-package-itself-specifies-a-main-module-field-that-could-not-be-r)
- [Github issues 26380](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26380)

Please help!!!

Error:-

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `fs` from file `/Users/***/***/node_modules/yargs/lib/completion.js`, the package `/Users/***/***/node_modules/fs/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/***/***/node_modules/fs/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * /Users/***/***/node_modules/fs/index.js(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * /Users/***/***/node_modules/fs/index.js/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at /Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
    at _next (/Users/***/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
```

Dependencies:-

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^1.1.7",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^2.2.0",
    "aws-appsync": "^3.0.2",
    "buffer": "^5.4.3",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.2.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-ux-cam": "^5.1.15",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-viewport-units": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-voice": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
```