# Error from Metro Bundler when starting up the iOS simulator, 'main' module field in 'idb-keyval' node-module can't be located

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules, metro-bundler

So the error arises when I try to open the iOS simulator from Metro Bundler. This is the second project where I am getting this error, both to do with the node-module 'idb-keyval'. Error only first occurred yesterday and, though I don't know why it would be related, first occurred after I updated NPM to 8.6.0 and then proceeded to install a package.

In the second project, the project that this particular error message is from, the error occurred after npm install'ing Parse.

### Below is the full error message:

While trying to resolve module `idb-keyval` from file `/Users/[username]/Development/[projectname]/node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/IndexedDBStorageController.js`, the package `/Users/[username]/Development/[projectname]/node_modules/idb-keyval/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/[username]/Development/[projectname]/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /Users/[username]/Development/[projectname]/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- /Users/[username]/Development/[projectname]/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)

---

If anyone can help me figure out what's going on it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: had the same issue, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70555971/18931181