# How to solve "Error: icon not found for icon = null"?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

Am trying to use an icon from FontAwesom library with React-Native, and this is the import statement:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faLock,faAirFreshener,faAnchor, faUserLock } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

And this is the code where I used it:

```
     <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserLock} size={40} color={"white"} />
     </View>
```

When I run the code, the icon appear, but with this error attached in image!
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTPnm.png)
Note: am using react-native CLI, not expo!

How to solve it?

Comment: Could you add your installed packages?

Comment: react-native-svg, @fortawesome/fontawesome-free, @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core, @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons, @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome, @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Might also be helpful to list the versions of these packages. It probably won't work, but you could try [resetting the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache).

Comment: @Abd26s Did you ever find a solution? I am getting the same behavior after the last update to RN 0.64.3.