# Unable to resolve "./rules/FieldsOnCorrectType" from "node_modules/graphql/validation/index.js"

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo-client

I'm building a react native application with apollo client 3, and keep getting the following error when generating the javascript bundle.

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "./rules/FieldsOnCorrectType" from "node_modules/graphql/validation/index.js"
```

My code is pretty simple, this is `App.tsx`:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import useColorScheme from './hooks/useColorScheme';
import Navigation from './navigation';

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
        <StatusBar />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tracked it down to the instantiation of the new ApolloClient object - commenting out those lines (and the provider) causes the error to disappear.

Renaming `node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectTypeRule.js` to `node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js` (dropping the `Rule` suffix of filename) fixes that specific error, but then errors on the next import in the `validation/index.js` file... I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a react native app after upgrading to apollo client 3. For me it was a react native caching issue and the problem went away after following these instructions to clear the cache: [How to clear react-native cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache).

I am using the react native cli and used these commands (I didn't check if all of them are actually necessary):

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf /tmp/metro-cache
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

If you are using the expo cli then apparently you can just do this:

```
expo start -c
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Please include the instructions in your answer to ensure it remains valuable if the link becomes invalid in the future.