# React Native: The development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: react-native

I tried to run my application on the emulator, the build is successfully done but when the app starts to bundle on about 26% this error pops up to the cmd:

```
[Mon Nov 08 2021 13:00:11.720]  BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\iarch\Desktop\Directik App\mobile-v2-new\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:586:33)
    at C:\Users\iarch\Desktop\Directik App\mobile-v2-new\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\iarch\Desktop\Directik App\mobile-v2-new\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\iarch\Desktop\Directik App\mobile-v2-new\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

and on the emulator splash screen shows up and then red screen appears:

[image]

i tried to solve with this versions of node:

```
17.0.1
16.13.0
16.10.0
14.18.1
```

and for every single one, I delete `node_modules` folder and then change my node version with `nvs` and afterward I run `npm install` but same thig happened.
how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for me this was due to the way I run project on emulator.
if you just run `npm run android` and wait for bundler to show up on another terminal,try this:
open up a terminal and run `npm start` on it wait for the react logo to show up.
then open another terminal and `npm run android`.
I don't know why but this worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It's Javascript code error very often found when we are connecting API's and the server is damaged/down so... Useful link is below I found help in Mozila Docx
6.6.1. 500 Internal Server Error
The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Reference Document

> https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.500

Answer (score 0):

You may try restarting the bundler without caches:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to clear everything and restart the server from there:

```
watchman watch-del-all && 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rm -rf node_modules/ 
&& npm cache clean --force &&
npm install && 
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Taken from: [How to clear react-native cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache)

---

If nothing else works, are you sure you don't have an error in your code?

Answer (score -2):

You first nedd to install react native community by given command

**npm i @react-native-community/cli**

Then you need you install react-timer-mixin as they help us to develop a faster responced server

**npm install react-timer-mixin**

This might solve your issue

Comment: How is `react-timer-mixin` useful in this situation

Comment: If you include TimerMixin, then you can replace your calls to setTimeout(fn, 500) with setTimeout(fn, 500) and everything will be properly cleaned up for you.