# using react-native-app-auth in react native app and login using MS API for login creates a token in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using react-native-app-auth package to do my sign in process with MS Graph API.
The problem that I face here is,

When we do the login using,

```
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
  issuer: '<YOUR_ISSUER_URL>',
  clientId: '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>',
  redirectUrl: '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URL>',
  scopes: ['<YOUR_SCOPES_ARRAY>'],
};

const result = await authorize(config);
```

And this opens the MS Authentication page in an in-app browser(from the react native app) and there it asks for username/password and does the authorization and returns back to the app(react native) with the access token.

Problem:
When I open the safari browser and open office.com or outlook.com and click on **sign in** it automatically takes to the home page without asking for credentials.

But we don't want this to happen. Any idea to prevent or sort this out?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
RJ

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Oauth authentication to login for react native app , [sample code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-react-native/blob/main/demo/GraphTutorial/auth/AuthManager.ts) , if you want to know more , please check - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-react-native

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {authorize, refresh, AuthConfiguration} from 'react-native-app-auth';
import moment from 'moment';

import {AuthConfig} from './AuthConfig';

const config: AuthConfiguration = {
  clientId: AuthConfig.appId,
  redirectUrl: 'graph-tutorial://react-native-auth/',
  scopes: AuthConfig.appScopes,
  additionalParameters: {prompt: 'select_account'},
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it would be great if we can suggest some for react-native.

Comment: Apologize for that i given react code , add code for react native please check my updated ans above. Hope this will help , thanks .

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this code helps to select account during login in app, but the actual issue that i mention here is, Once I do the login in the app and close the app. Open the device default browser(safari or chrome) and hit office.com, it directly opens the home page and not asking for login.

Comment: As you can see the authorizationEndpoint in my above code , when you add that in your code , it will redirect you the the login page , once you login you will get the token , which will add in tokenEndpoint , could you please try above code once , hope that will work. Thanks

Comment: I would like to give a more elaborate description of the issue. 
The config that you have given is the one that I'm using as well. But the issue that I face is once the login is done using the react-native app.
I open the normal browser and hit office.com it automatically redirects me to the home page without asking for credentials in the browser which is what my issue is.

Comment: Thanks Raja for elaborating , could you please provide us the your detailed code snippet , it helps us to investigate what's going wrong in your code . thanks

Comment: Sure, actually I found the root cause of this issue, when we are using react-native-app-auth module. It uses the device global browser for login and so once we login using Microsoft credentials it sets some cookies in the browser as per traditional login and so when we directly go the browser and hit office.com it take directly to the home page.

I want this issue to be sorted. either different modules or ms auth module. but still couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @Raja , we investigate on this , this looks more specific to browser thing , could you please try by gracefully signout of the app, in that case, and let us know if you get SSO when logging into office.com in the browser? you can also try with npm start -- --reset-cache , similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache

Answer (score 0):

After a struggle was able to understand that, as per the latest updates on security SSO is made mandatory where if we use the default browser or system browser it will store the cookies and make our login when we open the browser it automatically does the login.