# react-native-sqlite-storage: How to update the database?

Tags: react-native

I hope some will help me here, I tried for hours solving this problem.

I developed an Android app using react-native-sqlite-storage [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage).

All worked fine ... until I made changes to my database.

I'm not able to see my changes while running the app. I tried [to clear the cache as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878638/how-to-clear-react-native-cache) ... and this from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/qugyrj/react_native_sqlite_db_location/)

I found a database file in the data directory of the app ... I deleted it, without any effect.

I'm new to React Native ... I'm using npx --verbose react-native run-android to start the app.

What must I do to update the database file on my Android device?

Thanks in advance, Frank